# Put sum of values in center of doughnut chart?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js

I'm drawing this pie chart:

[image]

using this code:

```
dxPieChart: {
    dataSource: dsAlarmsBySeverity,
    size: {
        width: 275,
        height: 150
    },
    palette: ['#FFFF00', '#FF9900', '#CC3300', '#33CC33', '#0066FF'],
    legend: {
        backgroundColor: '#FCFCFC',
        border: {
                color: 'black',
                width: .5,
                visible: true,
                cornerRadius: 10
        },
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'doughnut',
        argumentField: 'severity',
        valueField: 'count',
        label: {
            visible: false,
            font: {
                size: 16
            },
            connector: {
                visible: true,
                width: 0.5
            },
            position: 'columns',
            customizeText: function(arg) {
                return arg.argumentText
            }
        },
        border: {
            color: 'black',
            width: .5,
            visible: true
        },
        hoverStyle: {
            border: {
                color: 'black',
                width: .5,
                visible: true
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Is there a way to add the sum of all values to the center of the donut?  Like so:

[image]

Comment: This feature is an open issue in [github](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/78)

Comment: The issue @SaravanaKumar refers to has been closed. You could use this plugin now: https://github.com/ciprianciurea/chartjs-plugin-doughnutlabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin for what you want to do: https://github.com/ciprianciurea/chartjs-plugin-doughnutlabel

Comment: is there a way to disable the labels in doughnut chart and only show the label in the center of the chart? When using the plugin the chart labels are always shown, even when tooltips and legend are disabled.

here an example forked from the offical github documentation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gimlnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-doughnut%2Fmy-doughnut.component.ts

Comment: @Ben It is a bit strange, as the example on https://ciprianciurea.github.io/chartjs-plugin-doughnutlabel/samples/index.html doesn't show the labels. But the Angluar app seems to have this "bug"!? And I can't see the difference in the codes. Maybe you should open an issue on theit Git hub page.

Comment: adding the following code to plugins option solved the issue for me: 
datalabels: {
    display: false
}

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround until the open issue is complete, you could just draw your own total on the canvas element itself.

You will have to manually calculate the x/y position on the canvas (like [150,100] in this example).

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("myChart");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="36px verdana";
ctx.fillText("76",150,100);
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up doing this:

```
<div style="position: relative;" data-bind="dxPieChart: {
  //chart initialization code from above...
}">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -15px; left: 50%; font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px; margin-left: -50px; width: 100px; text-align: center;" data-bind="text: alarmIDs().length"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: 15px; left: 50%; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; margin-left: -50px; width: 100px; text-align: center;">alarms</div>
</div>
```

When it binds the chart it doesn't overwrite any internal HTML, so this works brilliantly.