# display total in center of donut pie chart using google charts?

Tags: google-visualization

I am new to angularjs and google charts i made a pie chart now i want following:

```
1- display total components inside the centre of the pie charts.
2- display pieSliceText outer side of the pie slice
```

you can see the 
this is what i want:[image]

how can this be done
my sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}">                    </script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

javascript:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work',     11],
        ['Eat',      2],
        ['Commute',  2],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {     
        height: 360,
        width: 360,
        pieHole: 0.5,
        showLables: 'true',
        pieSliceText: 'value',
        pieSliceTextStyle: {
            color: 'white',
            fontSize:18
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            alignment: 'center'
        },
        chartArea: { 
            left: 10, 
            top: 10, 
            width: '130%', 
            height: '65%'
        },
        tooltip: {
            trigger:'none'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Partial duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911919/put-sum-of-values-in-center-of-doughnut-chart

Comment: @KevinBrown look at booth question huge difference b/w tow because i am using google charts for pie charts and i want to display the total number of components not all components some of values.

Comment: Well I don;t think so. But still. Have you read this article and attempting any part of it? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays

I took your chart and used this to put the middle component in. The labels would probabaly require moving them with JS after drawing the chart.

Comment: @KevinBrown i read doc on google developer for google charts but could't find a way to display the some of components inside donuts as in snapshot could you please create a plunker for it?

Comment: @in i am not making any object  like this new google.visualization.LineChart i just add data in variable and in my html place the google-charts directive < div class="chart-container">
          <div class="chart-title" style="padding-right:7em;">Components</div>
          <div google-chart chart="userdata"></div>
        </div>

Answer (score 6):

OK, try this http://jsfiddle.net/L1tct3Lv/3/ ... its a fast hack but you could certainly vastly improve it by calculating the positions based on sizes and such.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

<!-- This generates the google chart -->
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
]);

var options = {     
    height: 360,
    width: 360,
    pieHole: 0.8,
    showLables: 'true',
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize:18
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'right',
        alignment: 'center'
    },
    chartArea: { 
        left: 10, 
        top: 10, 
        width: '130%', 
        height: '65%'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger:'none'
    }
};
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
jQuery('#cnt').text(data.Gf.length);
chart.draw(data, options);
```

}

Setting up a few overlays like this:

```
<div id="JSFiddle">
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="cnt" class="overlay"></div>
<div class="overlay-label">total components</div>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
#JSFiddle {
position: relative;
}

.overlay {
display:block;
width:240px;
height:240px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: middle;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;  /* chartArea top  */
left: 0px; /* chartArea left */
font-size: 80px;
margin-top: 60px;
}
.overlay-label{
    display:block;
width:240px;
height:240px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: middle;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;  /* chartArea top  */
left: 0px; /* chartArea left */
margin-top: 140px;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Result is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Researching about this I found this link: https://codepen.io/cireriddler/pen/yyeLpE

This code isn't my, but I think that he answers the problem splitting the chart from the info inside chart.

Example:

```
<div id="donutchart" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <div id="labelOverlay">
    <p class="used-size">90<span>%</span></p>
    <p class="total-size">de economia mensal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```